# $M = -I_2$ or $M$ is similar to $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: matrices

I read a property that I did not understand:

> Let $M\in GL(2,\mathbb{F}_3)$ the matrix such that $M= I_2$ or $M^2=I_2$. As it has coefficients in a field of characteristic different from $2$, it is diagonalizable. So, $M = I_2$, $M = -I_2$ or $M$ is similar to $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ .

*Problem:* Why  $M = -I_2$ or $M$ is similar to $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Do you understand the term, "diagonalizable"? Do you understand the term, "similar"?

Comment: Yes I know these notions

Comment: OK. So, if $M$ is diagonalizable, then it is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$ whose square is the identity. There are only four of these: $\pm I$ and $\pm A$, and $-A$ is similar to $A$, and the only matrices similar to $\pm I$ are $\pm I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $M^2=I_2$. Then the eigenvalues of $M$ are among $1$ and $-1$.

If both are eigenvalues, then $M$ is diagonalizable, so it is similar to a diagonal matrix having the eigenvalues on the diagonal, in whatever order you prefer. Thus $M$ is similar to
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}

It is also similar to
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
but there is no problem: these two matrices are similar to one another using row and column swapping.

The interesting part of the exercise is to show that if there is a single eigenvalue, then $M=I_2$ or $M=-I_2$. It's sufficient to prove that if the only eigenvalue is $1$, then $M=I_2$ (justify it).

Over the complex numbers one could use the Jordan canonical form, which could also be used here, by passing to the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_3$, but it would be overkill. Suppose
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then the characteristic polynomial is $X^2-(a+d)X+(ad-bc)$, so we have
$$
a+d=2,\quad ad-bc=1
$$
by the assumption on the eigenvalues.

Hence $a(2-a)-bc=1$. Now we have $a\in\{0,1,2\}$ and it's sufficient to check the various cases.

If $a=0$, then we need $bc=-1$, so $c=-1/b$, but this contradicts $M^2=I_2$ (check it).

If $a=1$, then $bc=0$; if $c=0$, we see that $M^2=I_2$ implies $2b=0$, so $b=0$. Similarly, $b=0$ implies $c=0$.

If $a=2$, then we're in the same situation as for $a=0$.